# Given a successor set $A$, why is the set of all successor sets included in $A$ non-empty?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology

This question is related to Halmos' *Naive Set Theory*.

He says in section 11 on Numbers:

> For every set $x$ we define the *successor* $x^+$ of $x$ to be the set obtained by adjoining $x$ to the elements of $x$; in other words,
>   $$ x^+ = x \cup \{x\}.$$

And also:

> We shall say, temporarily, that a set $A$ is a *successor set* if $0 \in A$ and if $x^+ \in A$ whenever $x \in A$. In this language the axiom of infinity simply says that there exists a successor set $A$. Since the intersection of every (non-empty) family of successor sets is a successor set itself (proof?), the intersection of all the successor sets included in $A$ is a successor set $\omega$.

I am comfortable with the fact that the intersection of a non-empty family of successor sets is another successor set. Here is what troubles me: Given a successor set $A$ guaranteed to exist by the axiom of infinity, why is the set 
$$U = \{x \in A : x \text{ is a successor set}\}$$ 
necessarily non-empty?

As a counter-example, I think (informally) of the natural numbers. They are themselves a successor set, but do not contain any successor sets as elements.

When he says "all the successor sets included in $A$", is he describing the set $U$ I have defined above, or something different? Is he actually talking about:
$$U = \{x \subset A: x \text{ is a successor set}\}?$$

Comment: Does $x^+$ mean $x+1$? Why not say $x+1$?

Comment: In the context of Halmos' text, what is this "1" you speak of?

Comment: I added Halmos' definition of $x^+$ for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "inclusion" has particular meaning in the Halmos text, which is "to be a subset of". See Section 1:

> If $A$ and $B$ are sets and if every element of $A$ is an element of $B$, we say that $A$ is a *subset* of $B$, or $B$ *includes* $A$, and we write
>   $$A \subset B$$
>   or
>   $$B \supset A.$$